# Why did Wendy break up with her girlfriend?

Tags: character, mindhunter-2017

From the middle of the second season of *Mindhunter*, the relationship between Dr Wendy Carr and the bartender Kay seems to be progressing well - they are even thinking about moving together. Since they are both lesbians in the more conservative 70s, they both have reasons to hide their relationship: Wendy is working for the FBI while Kay is hiding her sexuality from her ex-husband, to get better access to her son.

Yet, after witnessing such masquerade performed by Kay, Wendy gets very upset. Some times later, we can hear that conversation:

> **Kay** - You're not returning my calls. 
>   **Wendy**- I wasn't sure who was calling.  
>    **Kay**- What is that supposed to mean?  
>   **Wendy** I didn't know your voice went that high.
>   With your husband.  
>    **Kay** Ex-husband.
>   And I told you that relationship was complicated.  Why are you judging me?  
>   **Wendy** - I find it a little unnerving that someone who places honesty over everything else can lie quite so  
>    **Kay**- Lie?  
>   **Wendy**- Looking for another job? Somewhere in Edgewood? You were a completely different person.  
>    **Kay** Oh, and you're always who you are? Yes, I manipulate my ex so that I can have some sort of relationship with my son.  
>   **Wendy**- An inauthentic relationship.  
>    **Kay**- That is not your place to say.  
>   **Wendy**You know, if you had even a modicum of the honesty that you're endlessly hocking To think that you actually made me feel bad about myself.  
>    **Kay** - This is not about me. 
>   **Wendy**- This is entirely about you. Lecturing me to be one way, while you..  
>   **Kay** - I have never lectured you.
>   And if I have to change the tone of my voice when I talk to my son, that is light-years from a person who can't admit who they are. This is about you.  
>   **Wendy** You're right. This is about me.

Is that just pure hypocrisy from Wendy's end? She is happy to pretend to be "normal" in front of her colleagues, who could judge her for being gay but cannot understand that Kay might have to live the double life as well? Or is she afraid that Kay is a bit too good lier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your quote it seems the reason is:

1. Kay preached about being herself to Wendy
2. At the same time, Kay pretended to be something else in front of her ex-husband + son
3. Wendy got upset with the double standards, and felt that Kay was being dishonest towards her.